# Anaconda conda env create -f tfdl_env.yml (solving envirnoment: failed)

Tags: python, tensorflow, cmd, anaconda

I'm currently starting udemy's Guide to tensoflow course. And it's required to type 'conda env create -f tfdl_env.yml' on the command line after using cd to get to the unziped file 'Tensorflow-Bootcamp-master'.
But after doing so this poped off: 'Solving environment: failed' (I'm on windows btw and have just installed anaconda)
I've been searching for solutions but didn't find anyhting. Is there a solution to this problem?

[link to the picture of the command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkkkU.png)

Comment: please add a image of error, so it become easy for us to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solving environment can sometimes failed in conda, that is why, especially for machine learning libraries (I use it for everything though). Try to install every package using

```
conda install -c packagename conda-forge
```

That may take some time, but for me it was usually the solution

Sorry there may be some confusion.

1. Create environment of the name you want, without any specific packages
2. Activate environment conda activate env_name
3. Install all packages using forge

Comment: should I use : conda install -c packagename conda-forge,  Or :Create environment of the name etc...?

Comment: 1. create env, then enter the environment and install all the packages using forge :) that's usually takes care of solving the environment. Because what you are doing now, you create env and installing all packages using conda install, not conda-forge,

Comment: so just ust conda env create envname, then conda activate envname and start installing packages